# django: how to add slug as arguments in url tag using django

Tags: python, django, slug

i want to add slug in url using django like this `<a href="{% url 'base:tutorial-page' p.slug p.slug2 %}" </a>`  i dont really know how to pass in double slug in the url for example: i want to access the **html** page before going to the **tutorial** page related to html.

getting-started.html

```
{% for p in prglangcat %}>
      {{ p.title }}
      <a href="{% url 'base:tutorial-page' p.slug p.slug %}"  </a>
{% endfor %}
```

**strong text**

```
def gettingStarted(request):
    prglangcat = ProgrammingLanguagesCategory.objects.all()
    context = {
        'prglangcat': prglangcat
    }
    return render(request, 'base/getting-started.html', context)

def programmingLanguageTutorial(request, prg_slug):
    prglangcat = ProgrammingLanguagesCategory.objects.get(slug=prglangcat_slug)
    prglangtut = ProgrammingLanguageTutorial.objects.get(slug=prg_slug, prglangcat=prglangcat)
    context = {

        'prglangtut': prglangtut
    }
    return render(request, 'base/tutorial-page.html', context)
```

**models.py**

```
class ProgrammingLanguagesCategory(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    icon = models.ImageField(upload_to='programming-category', default="default.jpg")
    description = models.TextField(default="Learn ...")
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('programming-languages-category', args=[self.slug])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class ProgrammingLanguageTutorial(models.Model):
    prglangcat = models.ForeignKey(ProgrammingLanguagesCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=10000, unique=True, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=10000)
    description = models.TextField(null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='Tutorial Image', default="default.jpg", null=True)
    code_snippet = models.CharField(max_length=1000000000, null=True, blank=True)
    video_url = models.URLField(null=True)
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**urls.py**

```
app_name = 'base'

urlpatterns = [
        path('', views.index, name="index"),
        path('getting-started/', views.gettingStarted, name="getting-started"),
        path('getting-started/<slug:prglangcat_slug>/<slug:prg_slug>', views.programmingLanguageTutorial, name="tutorial-page"),
]
```

**traceback**

```
NoReverseMatch at /getting-started/
Reverse for 'tutorial-page' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['getting\\-started/(?P<prglangcat_slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/(?P<prg_slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use like keyword arguments and its accepted the same way, and its more explicit which argument is which.

Do like this:

```
<a href="{% url 'base:tutorial-page' prg_slug=p.slug prglangcat_slug=p.slug2 %}"  </a>
```

Comment: i tried it but it wasn't still working  - {% url 'base:tutorial-page' prg_slug=p.prg_slug prglangcat_slug=p.prglangcat_slug%}

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing in the second argument in:

```
def programmingLanguageTutorial(request, prg_slug):
```

Comment: please how should i pass it in

Comment: like this - def programmingLanguageTutorial(request, prg_slug, prglangcat_slug):

Comment: Yes that's working, but how to pass the slug in a link tag {%   url    'link-name'  
slug.slug %}. Is what I don't know how to do??

Comment: Your are forgetting the / at the end of the url path('getting-started/<slug:prglangcat_slug>/<slug:prg_slug>/'